# Product of two arbitrary elements in $O(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

An exercise in a book I'm reading asks to describe the product of two arbitrary elements in $O(2)$. I would like to solve the exercise but I got stuck. I know that an element in $SO(2)$ can be written as

$$ B = \left ( \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right ) \in SO(2)$$

and an element in $O(2) \setminus SO(2)$ as

$$ A = \left ( \begin{array}{cc} \cos \phi & \sin \phi \\  \sin \phi & - \cos \phi \end{array} \right )   \in O(2) \setminus SO(2)$$

Is there a way of describing the product without calculating each case separately? (by that I mean calculate $AB, BA, BB'$ and $AA'$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on determinant considerations, the product of two elements in $SO(2)$, or the product of two elements in $O(2)-SO(2)$, is in $SO(2)$. This should give you some direction as to what the form of the product should be. Also, computing $AB$ then computing $(AB)^{-1}$ is equivalent to computing $AB$ and $BA$, and since the inverse is easy to compute you really only have to compute $AB, BB'$, and $AA'$. Rotations are easy to multiply (just add the angles), so you just have to manually compute two products for which you know the general form of the outcome, which shouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Not sure what kind of description the exercise expects me to give but do you think it's enough to just note that multiplying two elements from the same set makes the product be in $SO(2)$ and multiplying two elements from different sets makes it be in $O(2)\setminus SO(2)$?

Comment: @learner Possibly. It can't hurt to get explicit formulas though, and I really think it won't be very hard. Use trigonometric sum formulas.

Comment: What do you mean by "computing $AB$ then $(AB)^{-1}$ is equivalent to computing $AB$ and $BA$"? Is this something resulting from looking at the explicit products?

Comment: @learner $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$, so once you've computed $AB$ you've computed $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ (note that inverse really is easy in orthogonal groups, it's just the transpose). Since you have a general formula for $AB$, you can plug in the angles for $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ instead, then take the transpose and you have $BA$. $B^{-1}$ has $2\pi-\theta$ as its angle, and $A^{-1}=A$.

Comment: I did it. But now I am wondering what I'm supposed to learn from this exercise. It seems uninsightful.

Comment: @learner As you travel further along in pure math it begins to seem that manual computation is unimportant and everything is lofty and cloudy and beautiful. It's not true, you still need to churn things out sometimes. That could be the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Think *geometrically*.

Observe that $B$ is the matrix of *rotation* by angle $\theta$ (clockwise), and that $A$ is the matrix of *reflection* through the line at angle $\phi/2$ (so that the $x$ axis goes to the line at angle $\phi$).

Comment: Yes I know that. I don't see how it helps.